# How to create Angular 4 component to be used in multiple Angular 4 projects? NOT angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-library

I want to create a component that can be used between multiple projects. Let's consider this, I have three different angular 4 projects A, B & C and there is no relation between the projects. Every project is running independently.

Now, the scenario is like this, I have to add a new feature in all three projects. So, instead of adding the feature in three projects one by one, I want to create a common/shareable component so that if there are any changes required in the future, I just can make a change in one place instead of changing in three places which will be convenient for maintaining.

I have already checked a similar question here:
[How can I share an Angular 2 component between multiple Angular 2 projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091687/how-can-i-share-an-angular-2-component-between-multiple-angular-2-projects)

I want to divide my questions as below:

1. Is there any way to share components between projects in Angular 4? is it an only custom library?
2. If I create a custom library and use it in multiple projects, will this affect the size of the existing projects since it will have so many dependencies by default? please correct me here if it is not.

Your recommendation and suggestion is very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Angular Elements, custom library, or import the new component module in all 3 projects.

Comment: Edited the title of the question @R. Richards, Sajeetharan

Comment: The existing project developed using angular 4, not angular 6. I don't understand why this question has been marked as duplicate.